# Reputation graph tiny bug

Tags: bug, reputation-page

I found small bug in reputation graph: if you enter start date before your registration date, or end date in future pink rectangle size becomes bigger than border for it:
[Reputation graph http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/6816/reputationgraph.png](http://img80.imageshack.us/img80/6816/reputationgraph.png)

My registration date is after 2009/09/10 and today is 2009/12/04 (date before 2009/12/07)

Browser: IE8

Comment: Your image isn't showing at all. You must be missing a certain something with it to display properly.

Comment: @random - Shows for me.

Comment: @random - Shows for me too.

Comment: Looks like you both have no souls http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/cry-for-me-paint-gintina/19775#19775

Comment: @random - corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reputation graph has changed pretty drastically since this was an issue, and it is no longer a problem.